# GWT 2.6.0 - Uncaught java.lang.ClassCastException

Tags: javascript, java, debugging, gwt

I am using GWT 2.6.0 in Super Dev Mode (with IntelliJ Idea 14 + Chrome 43.0.2357.130 (64-bit) for Linux).

I have an exception in Chrome console during page loading

```
Uncaught java.lang.ClassCastException Impl.java:99
(anonymous function) @ Impl.java:99
gwtOnLoad @ oldstar-0.js:87303
(anonymous function) @ ClassLiteralHolder.java:23
```

`Impl.java:99` is **throw e;** in `com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl`

```java
 public static native JavaScriptObject entry(JavaScriptObject jsFunction) /*-{
    return function() {
      try {
        return @com.google.gwt.core.client.impl.Impl::entry0(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)(jsFunction, this, arguments);
      } catch (e) {
        // This catch block is here to ensure that the finally block in entry0
        // will be executed correctly on IE6/7.  We can't put a catch Throwable
        // in entry0 because this would always cause the unhandled exception to
        // be wrapped in a JavaScriptException type.
        throw e;
      }
    };
  }-*/;
```

`oldstar-0.js:87303` is **$entry(init_2)();** in generated oldstar-0.js

```js
function gwtOnLoad(errFn, modName, modBase, softPermutationId){
  $moduleName = modName;
  $moduleBase = modBase;
  if (errFn)
    try {
      $entry(init_2)();
    }
     catch (e) {
      errFn(modName);
    }
   else {
    $entry(init_2)();
  }
}
```

```java
package com.google.gwt.lang;

final class ClassLiteralHolder {
}
```

And also **init_2()** which is the reference to to `init() in EntryMethodHolder.java`

```java
package com.google.gwt.lang;

/**
 * This class holds the boot strap entry method that the compiler generates.
 */
public class EntryMethodHolder {
  public static final void init() {
    // Filled in by the compiler to call entry methods.
  }
}
```

Comment: I would add an UncaughtExceptionHandler. Look here for a really good post about logging in GWT: http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2012/06/11/7-tips-for-exception-handling-in-gwt

Answer (score 0):

The pasted code is the border between JS and Java, and is extremely unlikely to have thrown this exception (dare I say impossible).

As the message indicates, it is an *uncaught* exception that was thrown somewhere else in your code and was caught by this wiring before it leaked out from Java and into JS.

I *think* your EntryPoint is called by the EntryMethodHolder.init - this strongly implies that your EntryPoint is throwing a ClassCastException when your app tries to start up, but the UncaughtExceptionHandler (if you have one...) isn't yet set up to handle this.

Try looking at what is in your onModuleLoad, or adding a try/catch to nail down where this is coming from.

Comment: Also, you can ask Chrome to stop at each **thrown** exception.